# How to visualize a codeigniter array from a query on my view?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

On my model I have the following function which is a query to inner join 3 tables

```
function get_all_listaproveedorfamilia($clave)
{
    $this->db->select('proveedor.razonSocial, proveedor.nombre1, proveedor.telefonoFijo1, proveedor.telefonoMovil1, proveedor.correoElectronico1, proveedor.tipo, familia.clave');
    $this->db->from('proveedor');
    $this->db->join('relacionproveedorfamilia', 'relacionproveedorfamilia.idProveedor = proveedor.id', 'inner');
    $this->db->join('familia', 'familia.id = relacionproveedorfamilia.idFamilia', 'inner');
    $this->db->where('familia.clave', $clave);
    $this->db->order_by('proveedor.razonSocial');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query->result_array();
    }
}
```

The $clave value is a string retrieved from a select dropdown, and I send it to my controller using ajax

Jquery function in my view to send $clave value

```
$('#idFamilia').change(function(){
        var clave = $("#idFamilia option:selected").text();

        if (clave != "Seleccione"){
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Proveedor/obtenerListaProveedorFamilia',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    clave: clave
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Here is the code from my controller, where I use the clave value and call the function in my controller

```
function obtenerListaProveedorFamilia(){
    $this->load->model('Proveedormodel');
    $clave = $_POST['clave'];
    $data['listaproveedorfamilia'] = $this->Proveedormodel->get_all_listaproveedorfamilia($clave);
    $data['_view'] = 'proveedor/index';
    $this->load->view('layouts/main',$data);
}
```

I want to visualize the array returned by the function to check if the query is working and getting the values i want to retrieve. I have already tried the following methods to visualize the array adding addtional code to my jquery function $('#idFamilia').change(function(){});

-Get the array from the view and check it on the browser's console

```
var test = <?php echo json_encode($listaproveedorfamilia); ?>;
console.log(test);
```

-Trying to append print_r to a pre tag

```
$('#prueba').append('<?php print_r($listaproveedorfamilia) ?>');
```

With both options I get the following PHP error on my view

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message:  Undefined variable: listaproveedorfamilia
Filename: proveedor/index.php
```

This error appears as soon as the page loads, but it should wait for the user to select an option from the select dropdown and then use that option to build the query. How can I fix this and check the content of my array?

Comment: Try to `var_dump($data['listaproveedorfamilia']);` in the controller. What's showing there?

Comment: @Xidh I'm sorry, how can I var_dump from the controller? Where can I see the output?

Comment: Just put the `var_dump` right after the creation of `$data['listaproveedorfamilia']` and add `exit` so you will be able to read it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the success method to your ajax call. This is where the data created at the server will be sent.

```
$('#idFamilia').change(function () {
    var clave = $("#idFamilia option:selected").text();

    if (clave != "Seleccione") {
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Proveedor/obtenerListaProveedorFamilia',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                clave: clave
            },
            success: function (returned) {
                console.log(returned);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

You can use your browser's web dev tool to see what the javascript console has logged.

Because we don't know what the view file contains it's hard to comment on what to expect.

Typically ajax calls are used to return html that return is put into the DOM using $("some_selector").html() or a variety of other DOM manipulation methods to update the current browser screen.

Another way to "visualize" the return would be to simply append it to what is already on the screen. This is not likely what you'll eventually want. But you'll be able to see what came back.

Change the success function to this

```
success: function (returned) {
    $('body').append(returned);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to see the array and also the whole html code for the page was shown in the conse, not sure why but at least I know the query works.